# Center H4 in a div without line breaking

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4); background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1); padding: 10px;">
    <span>Test</span>
    <h4 class="heading" style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="bitcoin:1DxitRffAqwXju71aF2HoHNBfjjLQFcAw3">1DxitRffAqwXju71aF2HoHNBfjjLQFcAw3</a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

This gives me this result: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37289435/prob-1.png

I want "Test" and the link "1Dxit.." in one line, but "Test" on the left site and the link centered.
When I add "display: inline;" to the h4 tag, it gives me this result: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37289435/prob-2.png

It's inline but the link isn't centered anymore.
What is the problem and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `H4` element has margins attached to it by default.  You'll need not only remove the top margin on the `H4`, but also give it a negative margin equal to the line height of the span.

Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/smnpL/

Comment: The margins are removed by my "heading" class but the -margin thing is too easy to be obvious. Thanks.

Comment: No, this is not because the "margin"... if you do that, your page will be not realy responsive. Putting things pixel by pixel (-29px) is a bad method because it's hardly maintainable.

FYI `<span>` is an inline element, `<h*>` is a block element
I will do this like that http://jsfiddle.net/smnpL/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PatrickFerreira, but I want the "Test" span on the left site and the link centered in the div. Is this possible without loosing responsivibility of the page?

Comment: The problem is they either need to be treated as one item, meaning they'll be joined together either in the middle or the left side, or they're two separate items, meaning they can't occupy the same space, unless you force them.

Comment: You can use float:left on the span, but then the link is centered between the right edge of the span and the right edge of the box, not in the whole box.

Comment: @namespace please see my answer below. I think can resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your css:

```
h4{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see demo:

http://jsbin.com/becit/1

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    .b {
        display:table;
        width:100%;
    }
    .b span {
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
        padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
    }
    .b h4 {
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
        word-break:break-all;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="b" style="border: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4); background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1);">
        <span>Test</span>
        <h4 class="heading" style="text-align: center;">
            <a href="bitcoin:1DxitRffAqwXju71aF2HoHNBfjjLQFcAw3">1DxitRffAqwXju71aF2HoHNBfjjLQFcAw3</a>
        </h4>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```